# Need some brief difference about interfaces and model?

Tags: magento2, model, service-contract

As we know save method by using modelfactory is deprecated i just want to know what is the alternative and how it is implemented because i tried API interfaces but at save i got stuck so kindly anyone give some details about what is the alternative for modelfactory and its use.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you mentioned Interfaces. Could you give more info about the error?

The Model save method is deprecated due to the fact that working with Database is `Resource Model` not Model.

So you can use the save method of Resource Model https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/455991062f38ea76fe3a656714b4a71856c4d8d0/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php#L396

You can open any Admin controller and check the Save method to see how Magento implement it. Please notice that some still use the old deprecated save method